# Como agregar correctamente las librerias de EmguCV a C#?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

Segun yo ya tengo agregadas las librerias de Emgu.CV en la carpeta raiz del proyecto pero cuado compilo me manda el siguiente error: Como si no estuvieran agregadas las librerias... ver foto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen de las referencias agregadas: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los using que utilizo son: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui la carpeta raiz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si alguien lo tiene favor de comentar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de un tiempo buscando respuesta a este error, el problema fue la version de las librerias, ya que yo instale la mas reciente.
Preguntando en grupos de facebook alguien me recomendo descargar versiones anteriores ya que las mas recientes tienden a tener algunos fallos, procedi a decargar versiones anteriores y copie todos los archivos necesarios nuevamente a la carpeta raiz del proyecto 
 compile el proyecto y me funciono correctamente.
Por si alguna persona tiene el mismo problema o algo parecido, es lo que hice para solucionarlo.
:D